# Retrieve and delete data in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

1. I have two tables in the database: `Document` and `User`. `UID` is a foreign key in `Document` table. I want to get all records from `Document` where `UID` is equal to current user ID. Suppose the ID is 1. How do I get all values from `Document` where `UID` is equal to `1`.
2. How can I delete all records where the user name is 1.

I want all this in the action method.

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string id=Session["LoggedUserID"].ToString();
            int UID=int.Parse(id);
            Database1Entities2 db = new Database1Entities2();
            var documents = (from d in db.MyDocuments
                             where d.UID == UID
                             select d.ToList());
            return View(documents);
        }
```

The code in view is:

```
@model List<string>
<table> 
    <tr>
         <th>File Name</th>
         <th>Download</th>
    </tr>
     @for (var i =0; i <= Model.Count -1; i++)
     {
         <tr>
              <td> @Model[i].</td>
              <td> @Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "Download", new { FileName=@Model[i].ToString() }) </td>
         </tr>
     }
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to include more detail, including the code you have tried.

Comment: Actually i have not tried any code because of no idea. I am new in C# and asp.net as well.

Comment: it should be like database db = new database();
db.Document.where(.......);

Comment: It needs to be something like `var userDocs = db.Document.Where(d => d.UID == userID);` but you have not posted enough information about your models to be sure

Comment: are you also using entity framework OR LINQ to sql? just asking how to delete data in asp.net MVC makes no sense

Comment: This question basically requests a tutorial on the basic use of Entity Framework or some other data access technology that can be used from ASP.NET MVC. As such, it is too broad for [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I would probably approach this would be to first [create an Entity Framework model in your project from the database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx).

Once you have the model in place, in your action method you can add code to manipulate that data. For instance, to select all documents from a given user ID you might have something like the following:

```
using (MyDatabaseEntityName database = new MyDatabaseEntityName)
{
    var documents = (from d in database.Document
                    where d.UID == userID
                    select d).ToList()
}
```

Likewise, to delete records from a given user *name* you might do something like this:

```
using (MyDatabaseEntityName database = new MyDatabaseEntityName)
{
    var userID = (from d in database.User
                 where d.UserName == userName
                 select d.UID).First();

    var documents = from d in database.Documents
                    where d.UserID == userID
                    select d;

    foreach (var document in documents)
    {
        database.Documents.DeleteObject(document);
    }

    database.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: but now how i can access to my table fields. I have fields of document name, document extension. i want to access it in view. I use this code as edited in question

Comment: The first block of code in my answer gives you a 'List<Document>' object named 'documents'. You should be able to iterate through that and access your fields using '.FieldName', ie. 'document.Name', 'document.Extension', etc.